# jquery doesnt know what option is selected

Tags: jquery, html

HTML:

```
<p>
    <label for="rolle">Rolle:</label> 
    <select id="rolle" style="float:right;width:154px;" name="rolle">
        <option value="1">Administrator</option>
        <option value="2">Autor</option>
    </select> 
</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#rolle').change(function()
    {
        if($('#rolle option[value="1"]:selected')) 
        {
            alert("YES");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You would need to check the `length` property if that collection were valid.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @DanielA.White dont know how to know with jquery if the option with value 1 is selected or the one with value 2, if it is with the value 1 I want that alert poping up, but it doesnt!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jQuery` functions return the `jQuery` object. If you want to know if any elements matched the query, you have to check the `length` property.

Change the JavaScript to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rolle').change(function(){
        if($('#rolle option[value="1"]:selected').length > 0) {
            alert("YES");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this too but the alert doesnt pop up

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FE8GM/ works for me... take into account the `change` event only gets fired if the `select`'s value actually changed.

Comment: I know how the change works but I dont know what is wrong maybe I am missing something..

Comment: I am using jquery-1.8.1.min.js do you think thats the problem?

Comment: I doubt the jquery version is the problem. Try setting up a jsfiddle with only the code related to the ´select´, it might help to isolate your problem

Comment: thank you thats what I am trying to do, I think that now nobody can't help because the code should work as I verified it with your code in jsfiddle. The problem must be me because probably I am missing something or doing something wrong here..

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply turn your conditional check around slightly to read this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rolle').change(function(){
        if($('#rolle option:selected').val() == "1") {
            alert("YES");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: With two answers which should both give you a result, there's likely something else happening. What debugging have you tried? Are you checking the results in Firebug / Chrome?

Comment: yes I am using the Chrome console for debugging but I and yet I dont know whats the problem because the solutions work on jsfiddle! do you think the problem is with the jquery that I am using: jquery-1.8.1.min.js

Comment: The jQuery version is unlikely to be the issue - especially if your tests in jsFiddle are working. What results are shown for your `#rolle option:selected` collection in the debugger? Have you tried sending the results of the `$(#rolle option).length` to the console? What is the output?